# Display only entries relevant to users' country

Tags: entries, relations, pagination, craft-pro

I'm really struggling with displaying news entry that are only relevant to the users' location.

Here is my structure:

**User**

Country - > is a dropdown with a single value (lets say UK)

**Regions** is a category that contains

name -> string (for example Europe)

countries -> a checkbox with a list of countries (UK, FR.. etc)

**News** which has a Region category

So what I have now is this:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('news') %}
{# loop through regions  #}  
    {% for region in entry.regions %}
        {# loop region's countries  #}
        {% for targetCountry in region.countries %}
            {% if targetCountry == currentUser.country %} 
                {% set visibility = true %}  
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This works, however, since the checking occurs after I get all the entries I can't use pagination. Is there a nicer way of doing this?

Comment: Try changing the outer loop to the paginate tag `{% paginate craft.entries.section('news').relatedTo(entry).limit('12') as variablename %}` which doesn't need a closing tag or this link might help https://mijingo.com/blog/using-categories-in-craft-cms

Comment: @mention79 , sorry don't get it, can you be a bit more specific, please?

Comment: So refering specifically to the pagination point at the end of our post. I meant change the first line of code `{% for entry in craft.entries.section('news') %}` to something like `{% paginate craft.entries.section('news').relatedTo(entry).limit('12') as regions %}` the `.relatedTo(entry)` bit is to reference the categories linked to the entry and `.limit('12')` would give you 12 entries before it did a new page. And the final bit is the variable name that gets referenced in the for loop below. So `regions` and then in the one below it would change to `{% for region in regions %}`

Comment: If I replace the first loop with your suggestion, I'm getting an error message because '.relatedTo(entry)' is relating to something that doesn't exist as there is no entry at this point. Am I missing something?

Comment: Drop the `.relatedTo(entry)` possibly

Comment: I see where you're going with it, but this will lead to unequal number of items on a page, as after dividing data into pages, some of it may or may not be displayed for the user country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One nice way to handle things like this is to collect the ids for all the entries you want, use those ids for the [ElementCriteriaModel](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel) you need for the pagination, and then paginate.

Collect the ids (use [merge](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/filters/merge.html) to create an array of the ids):

```
{% set ids = [] %}

{% for entry in craft.entries.section('news') %}
  {# loop through regions  #}  
  {% for region in entry.regions %}
    {# loop region's countries  #}
    {% for targetCountry in region.countries %}
      {% if targetCountry == currentUser.country %} 
        {% set ids = ids | merge([entry.id]) %}  
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Get the entries for pagination:

```
{% set unpaginated = craft.entries({
  id: ids,
  limit: 10
}) %}
```

Finally, the pagination:

```
{% paginate unpaginated as pageInfo, pageEntries %}
...
```